# Find Icon from the current LookAndFeel

Tags: swing, user-interface, java-7, jtree, uimanager

I have an application that I'm creating a `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`. For that I want to show the default system icon from `File` and `Directory`.

At the start from the application I'm setting the System Look and Feel

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Set System L&F
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new App().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

All UI have the System Look and Feel. But when I create a `JTree` with my custom `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`, I'm return `DefaultTreeCellRenderer#getIcon` the `static` fields bellow.

```
private static final Icon FILE             = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");
private static final Icon FOLDER           = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
```

The result is that the default values are from system. But the `FILE` and `FOLDER` are pointing to the default `LookAndFeel`.

[image]

How can I get the values from the System `Look And Feel`? To have all the same icons.

Comment: `Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);`  E.G. as seen in the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Comment: No, that's not the point. Is just the system icon for file. In my case I'm building a Tree for a remote FileSystem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I someone have already the same problem will know how to help me. In some cases It's difficult to write a MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the FILE and FOLDER are pointing to the default LookAndFeel.

Well try setting the LAF for the systems you want to handle. Something like:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( laf1 );
Icon laf1Icon = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");
Icon laf1Folder = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( laf2 );
Icon laf2Icon = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");
Icon laf2Folder = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
//...
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( backToTheDefault );
```

You can see the results of this approach by checking out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). As the change the LAF the Icons changes. Of course this will only work for LAF's available on your system, not all possible remote file systems.

Comment: `UIManager.getIcon` is only returning the default from java. Nothing change after `UIManager.setLookAndFeel`

Comment: @Victor, Read the Swing tutorial on [Changing the LAF After Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic). Maybe you need to update the component tree. Did you try the code I provided in the link because it works fine.